# How to filter the object inside object in angular 2?

Tags: angular, filter

I have a JSON Like this:

```
filteredArray = [
    {
    "Key":"Brochure",
    "Value":[{
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"Accounting",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        },
        {
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup 1",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        }]
    },
    {
    "Key":"Handout",
    "Value":[{
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup 2",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        },
        {
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup 3",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        }]
    }
]
```

I have to filter the data on the bases of Industry in Angular 2.

I am using this query in pipe in Angular 2 but the data is not getting filtered.

```
filteredArray.filter(
    item => item.Value.filter(
        innerItem => innerItem.Industry.match(industry)))
```

Comment: what do you mean by filter on industry? do you need to group by specific industry types?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Post the desired output from the code

Comment: I have to filter this json data in the same format but the should be filtered on the bases of Industry i.e if industry matches to Accounting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `Array.filter` and `Array.some`

```
let s = this.data.filter((d) => {
      d.Value = d.Value.filter(d1 => {
        if (d1.Industry === "Accounting") { // here put your condition
          return d1;
        }
      });
      if (d.Value.length > 0) {
        return d;
      }
    });
```

```js
var data = [
    {
    "Key":"Brochure",
    "Value":[{
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"Accounting",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        },
        {
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup 1",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        }]
    },
    {
    "Key":"Handout",
    "Value":[{
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup 2",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        },
        {
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup 3",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        }]
    }
];

var s = data.filter((d) => {
  d.Value = d.Value.filter(d1 => { 
   if(d1.Industry === "Accounting") {
   return d1;
   }
   });
   if(d.Value.length > 0){
   return d;
   }
});
console.log(s);
```

Comment: This will not work as I am also using the same but the data is not getting filtered if you check.

Comment: @AyoushKohli try running the snippet it works here and also you forgot to return the inner result i am using some and you are using filter these are the differences

Comment: The result should be only one result but as per your script the results are two object that is wrong.

Comment: what should be the result

Comment: :The result should be only one object if you check the json there is only one Industry that matches Accounting but as per your script the results are two object that is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. it Works!!

Answer (score 0):

Need to return data from both filters:

```js
var filteredArray = [
    {
    "Key":"Brochure",
    "Value":[{
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"Accounting",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        },
        {
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup 1",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        }]
    },
    {
    "Key":"Handout",
    "Value":[{
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup 2",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        },
        {
            "Title":"Accounting Services",
            "service":"Accounting",
            "Location":"",
            "Industry":"",
            "Reprint":"Request",
            "Contact":"Mike Astrup 3",
            "Updated":"04/15/2017",
            "Owner":"EB",
            "Status":"Approved",
            "online":"true",
            "Type":"Material",
            "Url":".common/service"
        }]
    }
]

var test = filteredArray.filter((item) => {
  return item.Value.filter((Initem) => {
   return (Initem.Industry == "Accounting") //Filter for Accounting industry
 })
})

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

But this will not work as I am also using the same but the data is not getting filtered.

Comment: @AyoushKohli It is a working sample. I dont know how you can say it is not working?